# Private variable accessing

Tags: c#, private

what is the use of declaring

```
private Int64 _ID ;
public Int64 ID{get { return _ID; }set { _ID = value; } };
```

like this to declare a private variable

now normally in the coding we use ID directly which in turn access the _ID which is private.
How this offers more security instead of directly declaring as

```
public int64 ID{get;set;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the `benefit` of encapsulation by get and set method to be call where you can put your `custom logic`. The private `_ID` is a place holder to hold the data for your property which is `protected` by set method when some body writes to `_id`, similarly you can put custom logic before giving the value by `get`.

This is what `msdn` explains about properties "*Properties combine aspects of both fields and methods. To the user of an object, a property appears to be a field, accessing the property requires the same syntax. To the implementer of a class, a property is one or two code blocks, representing a get accessor and/or a set accessor. The code block for the get accessor is executed when the property is read; the code block for the set accessor is executed when the property is assigned a new value. A property without a set accessor is considered read-only. A property without a get accessor is considered write-only. A property that has both accessors is read-write*". You can read more over [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply if I write something like this
private Int64 _ID {get;set;} ;
public Int64 ID{get { return _ID; }set { _ID = value; } };

what is the difference

Comment: Actually my basic doubt is that if we are writing something like this notation, having private field and public prop, we are having the advantage of having the business logic but aren't we making the private field to a public one

Answer (score 4):

Best of both:

```
public long ID {get;set;}
```

Wasn't that easier?

You should not expose fields as `public`, but that doesn't mean you need to be verbose either.

Comment: That is right but I would like to provide security,  if I use  like above then I am actually making the variable which is public and I don't want that .

Comment: **You should not expose** - though this might be a topic of discussion ;) IIRC Jeffrey Richter is a strong supporter of NOT using properties at all and though one not always has to follow his reasoning, he makes some valid points against properties and PRO (public) fields.

Comment: @Raghurocks no, the above **does not** make the variable (meaning: field) public; further, you can add whatever logic you need at a later date without changing the API to the caller

Comment: @Raghurocks well, I'm going to disagree with that blog. That assumes you *have* invariants that need maintaining, but the point is: once something is an auto-prop, you can change it *later* to add more logic without breaking the interface that is exposed to the caller. That is **not true** of a public field: any change to a prop later is a fundamentally breaking change.

Comment: @igrimpe I know there are some cases where you want to formally state: "this *is the implementation**", and thus exposing fields can be (in some very specific cases) desirable, but that is a **minority** of cases. For most day-to-day line-of-business etc programming, it simply doesn't apply.

Comment: @MarcGravell so here, let us consider a situation, we have a class named Class1 in that the field is defined as public long ID{get;set;} so as this is public I can access it from even other class, by creating the object to the Class1 class, so if I change the data and give some false data how we can apply the business logic to avoid the false data. But if we declare like I said private field and public property, there I can get the scope of business logic to avoid false data.

Comment: @MarcGravell actually I found this as one of the advantage if we declare like I said, but now I would like to know are there any other advantages like so. Thanks @ MarcGravell

Answer (score 2):

You should read about [`Properties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) and [`Fields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx). Properties provide better encapsulation and should be used instead of exposing public fields.

Comment: One example of "why?" would be the ability to make the setter `private`. Now you have a property that is read-only from the outside.

Answer (score 2):

It bring security when you check the input or output before setting and getting values, look:

```
private int? _ID;
public int ID 
{
    get { return _ID ?? 0; }
    set { _ID = value >= 0 ? value : 0; } 
}
```

Comment: Of course @MarcGravell you are right, just wanted to show him you can control input and output, the example is not a practical one.